# next and back buttons using javascript

Tags: javascript, element

I am trying to find the current page in a ul and create a link to the previous or next li

I have a top menu in the structure of:

```
<ul id=menu>
  <li><a>Category A</a>
     <ul>
        <li><a>Sub Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a>Sub Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a>Sub Page 3</a></li>
      </ul></li>
 <li><a>Category B</a>
     <ul>
        <li><a>Sub Page 4</a></li>
        <li><a>Sub Page 5</a></li>
      </ul></li></ul>
```

The idea being if I am on page 4 the back button will take me to page 3, and the next will take me to page 5.

I can get my current filename with

```
 var url = window.location.pathname;
 var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
```

And the list of my links with

```
document.getElementById('menu');
```

And I am guessing once I match the filename to the links, I can use some form of next() & previous(), but I am not clear on how to find my variable filename in the code, and then select the next element.  And the elements are to be on the same level, so the next of page 3 goes to page 4, not page 4's parent category B.

I am not using jQuery, and would prefer a non jQuery code if that was possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work

```
function currentPath() {
  var url = window.location.pathname;
  return url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
}

function getHrefForLi(li) {
  return li.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href.split('/').pop();
}

var lis = document.getElementById('menu').getElementsByTagName('li');

for (var i = 0, n = lis.length; i < n; i++) {
  if (getHrefForLi(lis[i]) == currentPath()) {
    var prev = i > 0 ? getHrefForLi(lis[i-1]) : null,
        next = i < n - 1 ? getHrefForLi(lis[i+1]) : null;
    break;
  }
}
```

`prev` and `next` will be the value of the previous and next `<a>` tags `href` attribute values or `null` if the active path is the first or last.

Comment: Im getting an error - getElementsByTagName is not defined.  The code is running after the menu loads so Im not sure why this is?

Comment: In which line @Jon? See the doc for `getElementsByTagName` here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getElementsByTagName

Comment: I can't really help you if you're not trying the solution I've posted.

Comment: if (getHrefForLi(lis[i]) == currentPath()) is computing false.  I think its because currentPath gives just the filename, while getHrefForLi gives the path as well.  If I can get rid of the path from getHrefForLi then it should match up

Comment: I changed return li.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href; to return li.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].href.split('/').pop();   .   Now the vars next and prev are working! (wow) But I want to get rid of the null so the links will cross categories.  As now pevious on page 4 would be 4, not 3 etc  thanks

Comment: You should ensure that your method for getting the current path matches your `href` values.